# Saving changes to user account result in DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I have a form where the user can edit their user account information and then save the new changes.

The problem I'm getting happens when I save the modified changes to the database.

On the line context.SaveChanges(), I get a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception thrown. It says, `"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`"

I have no idea why.

Here's what I have done:

```
public ActionResult EditUserAccount()
{
    UserAccountViewModel editUserAccountViewModel = new UserAccountViewModel();
    editUserAccountViewModel.UserName = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.UserName, StateNameEnum.UserName.ToString()) as string;
    int UserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(editUserAccountViewModel.UserName);
    var userInfo = context.db_user.First(x => x.UserId == UserId);

    editUserAccountViewModel.Title = userInfo.Title;
    editUserAccountViewModel.FirstName = userInfo.FirstName;
    editUserAccountViewModel.LastName = userInfo.LastName;
    editUserAccountViewModel.PhoneNumber = userInfo.PhoneNumber;
    editUserAccountViewModel.AltPhoneNumber = userInfo.AltPhoneNumber;
    editUserAccountViewModel.EmailAddress = userInfo.EmailAddress;
    editUserAccountViewModel.UserAccountState = UserAccountViewModel.AccountState.EDIT;
    return (PartialView("~/Views/Account/UserAccount.cshtml", editUserAccountViewModel));

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserAccount_Save(UserAccountViewModel editUserAccountViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            editUserAccountViewModel.UserName = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.UserName, StateNameEnum.UserName.ToString()) as string;

            db_user user = new db_user();
            user.Title = editUserAccountViewModel.Title;
            user.FirstName = editUserAccountViewModel.FirstName;
            user.LastName = editUserAccountViewModel.LastName;
            user.PhoneNumber = editUserAccountViewModel.PhoneNumber;
            user.AltPhoneNumber = editUserAccountViewModel.AltPhoneNumber;
            user.EmailAddress = editUserAccountViewModel.EmailAddress;
            user.LanguageId = context.languages.Where(t => t.Code == editUserAccountViewModel.Language).Select(t => t.Id).SingleOrDefault();
            user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.UserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(editUserAccountViewModel.UserName);

            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            JsonResult res = Json(new { Success = true, data = "", Message = "" });
            return res;
        }
        else
        {
            JsonResult res2 = Json(new { Success = false, data = "", Message = "" });
            return res2;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating an instance of `context` within the controller action, which would imply that it is at the class level.  That means that `context` is shared with every other web request processed by that controller.  This part of the error message `Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded` seems to confirm that hypothesis.

Instead, create an instance of `context` in your controller action.

Since you are editing an existing user in this action, you will first need to load the existing user into the `context` from the database, rather than instantiating a new one as you are now.

I strongly suspect that this change will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

Here's a code example.  I don't know what your context class is called, so you might have to change that part.  I assume that the user must already exist when this controller is called (based on the name of the method).  I removed the `try` because you are not catching anything. If there is something useful you can do when an exception is thrown, go ahead and put that back in.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserAccount_Save(UserAccountViewModel editUserAccountViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            int userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(editUserAccountViewModel.UserName);
            db_user user = context.DbUsers.Where(u => u.Id == userId).Single();
            editUserAccountViewModel.UserName = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.UserName, StateNameEnum.UserName.ToString()) as string;

            user.Title = editUserAccountViewModel.Title;
            user.FirstName = editUserAccountViewModel.FirstName;
            user.LastName = editUserAccountViewModel.LastName;
            user.PhoneNumber = editUserAccountViewModel.PhoneNumber;
            user.AltPhoneNumber = editUserAccountViewModel.AltPhoneNumber;
            user.EmailAddress = editUserAccountViewModel.EmailAddress;
            user.LanguageId = context.languages.Where(t => t.Code == editUserAccountViewModel.Language).Select(t => t.Id).SingleOrDefault();
            user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            context.SaveChanges();

            JsonResult res = Json(new { Success = true, data = "", Message = "" });
            return res;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JsonResult res2 = Json(new { Success = false, data = "", Message = "" });
        return res2;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh okay, so 1) instantiate the context inside the controller action and 2) "load the existing user into context" what do you mean by this?

Comment: Okay thank you, btw, I am getting this error for the the loading user into context: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.db_user>' to 'Models.db_user'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Sorry I missed calling .Single().  Updated the code.

Comment: Thank you! Crosses fingers. Hope this works :) EDIT: one more issue for that user statement: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetUserId(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Edited.  Call needs to be separated out.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: what if I had a situation where db_user user = context.DbUsers.Where(u => u.Id == userId).Single();
returns null (sequence contains no elements -- not particularly when editing user details). So that means that the user did not have any entries and this is the first time they're adding these values. 
How can I proceed with this condition? I am reusing the above approach for other fields I have.

Comment: That would actually throw an exception, but you can substitute SingleOrDefault() to have it return null on no match.  If SingleOrDefault() returns no match, that means a user with that ID does not exist.  If that situation is OK, you can create a new object instance when null is returned and do context.Add(db_user);

Comment: Ah okay, I'll give it a try. I wouldn't expect it for edit user account but I am getting this error for some of the older accounts that did not have security questions set up previously in which case, I would have to add it to context. Thank you!